# DJI Go Android App Flight Simulator

Tags: smartphone-app, simulators, dji-phantom

So I have two DJI platforms, and have had them for about 6 months now. I keep seeing these references all over the Internet and YouTube about how handy it is to have the DJI simulator built into the app. And how great it is that you can just turn on the remote, configure it with your phone or tablet, just as if you were actually going to fly. But when I do all that and get to the first DJI Go app page, you know, where it shows which aircraft you can select, there is no simulator app.

So I'm running a DJI Phantom 3 Standard and a DJI Inspire 1 v2.0, both using the same DJI Go app. I'm all Android all, the time so hopefully it's not another one of these "iOS people get it but Android people don't" things.

I do have the DJI Windows 10 PC Simulator App downloaded onto the laptop. And much to my utter shock, after I connected the Inspire controller to the computer with a USB cable, a few false starts, the thing actually loaded and let me fly. But MANNNN is it dog slow. And let's be honest here, I'm pretty sure that downloading a DJI executable was probably not the best decision of my life. But you know what, have at it China, you guys already have literally every single byte of my personal data from when you stole all the Top Secret Clearance applications from OPM. Good thing it wasn't important or anything...

Anyway, didn't mean to digress. So, can anyone help me find, use, and enjoy the Android DJI Go App's Flight Simulator?

Comment: I don't have a DJI drone to hand to check myself, but if you click on the menu button on the aircraft selection screen is there an option for "Academy"? I believe the simulator may be under that.

Comment: @Kralc So, that's a very solid suggestion, or is it? It is, because that's where everyone else says to look too. But when I go to the Academy link, I have 3 options: Videos, Flight Tutorial, or User Manuals.

Comment: I wonder if it magically appears if I set it up with the controller prior to opening the app. I'll be pissed if so, they need to note that for people like me who are easily confused

Comment: I have a P3S too. I'll check later but I remember it to be very sluggish, at least on my old phone. But I can confirm that it is (or at least was until ~2 years ago when I tried it last time) available in the app. But I also remember that it was less useful than everyone stated

Comment: I can't find it anymore, too. It seems to be gone for good ([DJI Forum](https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=197212)). As I said, the experience was not great at all, so it's just a minor loss. To be honest though, the P3S is very easy to fly. So there's not a whole lot you can do wrong. Just do it in an open field. If you let go off the sticks, the drone will just hover (assuming you are in positioning mode. If you want to start small, enable beginner mode for the first flight. It restricts speed and range to 30m or so.

Answer (score 1):

I have found where the simulator went, no where. The problem I was having was related to a common theme I'm seeing with many drone apps.

The simulator seems to be available only with iOS versions of the DJI Go app. We converted over from Android for to an unrelated app offering more features with the iOS version than the app's Android version.

So if you're using an Android device and want to have the DJI app, you need to make the transition to an Apple iOS device.